# Listen on 22 port from specific IPs

Tags: 16.04, networking, ssh, amazon-ec2, port-forwarding

I've two test AWS EC2 instances with below IPv4 Public IPs

```
3.15.217.194
18.222.170.204
```

I want to listen SSH request from above two IPs on my local ubuntu machine to copy some files.

Here is my ufw status of local ubuntu machine (16.04)

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
54310                      ALLOW       Anywhere                  
54310/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Anywhere                   ALLOW       3.15.217.194              
22                         ALLOW       3.15.217.194              
22                         ALLOW       18.222.170.204            
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Anywhere                   ALLOW       18.222.170.204            
54310 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
54310/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

But when am doing the scp or ssh from AWS EC2 instance to my local ubuntu machine, I'm getting error

```
ssh: connect to host ubuntuPublicIP port 22: Connection timed out
```

Not sure why its coming. Ping is successfully happening from AWS EC2 to my local ubuntu machine with its public IP.

Done following steps on my local ubuntu machine:

1) Done port forwarding in my router on port 22 wrt my local machine IP.

2) Added `IPv4 Public IPs` in hostname file in local ubuntu machine.

3) SSH server is running

4) Here is output of `sudo iptables -nvL`

```
Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:54310
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:54310
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:54310
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       3.15.217.194         0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       3.15.217.194         0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       3.15.217.194         0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       18.222.170.204       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       18.222.170.204       0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
```

5) done `sudo ufw allow from 18.222.170.204`

6) done `sudo ufw allow from 3.15.217.194`

7) Re-booted router too after port forwarding

8) `sudo ufw allow 22/tcp`

I'm really kind of stuck from last 48 hours on this and really dont know now what do to ...!

Can anyone please help ...?

Update:

got machine public ip using this command: `curl ifconfig.me`

got my router IP using this command: `ip route | grep default`

Thanks

Comment: How did you find your public IPv4? Are you sure that you are not behind CGNAT?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli, I've got public IPv4 from AWS EC2 dashboard. How to check CGNAT ? I'm behind router ..! (Using wifi)

Comment: I am talking about your local network, not AWS. Login to your router and locate the "public" IP assigned to your router by your ISP. Please, also give more detail in your original question about how you have found your public IP.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli, That's how I've got my router IP address  "ip route show | awk '/default/ {print $3}"

Comment: @FedonKadifeli, My machine IP (public) is different, router IP is different..! How it wil work ..?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli, Update information in question ..! Please check

Comment: You say that you have done ip forwarding (step 1) on your router. This means that you have logged in to your router (which has ***local*** IP: `ip route | grep default`). While you have logged in to your router go to main page of your router and look at your ***public*** or ***WAN*** Internet IP address given to your router by your ISP. If this is not the *real* IP address (obtained by `curl ifconfig.me`), you are behind CGNAT. I found this simple page which explains shortly what is CGNAT: http://www.remoterig.com/wp/?page_id=3494

Comment: @FedonKadifeli, My WAN Ip and curl ifconfig.me is different ..! SO what can be done ..?

Comment: Assuming your ISP does not provide you with a real WAN IP, there is no easy way to connect from AWS to your SSH server at home. You can connect from your home computer to your AWS EC2 instances, assuming that those instances are running an SSH server (a Linux instance will have an SSH server by default). Another more difficult and probably problematic solution is to use **UDP Hole Punching** as I have described in my web page: https://kadifeli.com/fedon/hint.php?python_udphp ***Please note: If you decide to go this path (UDP H.P.), good luck; but do NOT try to request more help from me!***